# How to synthesize hardware for SRA instruction

Tags: mips, system-verilog, synthesis

How should I design my SRA MIPS R3000 instruction, which shifts arithmetic the Reg[rt] by the shift amount. The shift amount is always a variable and not a constant, so I am just concerned how do I specify it in the code to make it synthesizable, when writing in Systemverilog. Since a variable cannot be synthesized, unless its value is known. Please correct me if my question is wrong.

Shift Word Right Arithmetic SRA:
register rt are shifted right by shamt bits, sign-extending
the high-order bits.
The result is placed in register rd.

```
module ALU_SRA(
        input logic signed [31:0] rs,
        input logic signed [31:0] instr,
        input logic signed [31:0] rt,
        input logic signed [4:0] shamt,
        output logic signed [31:0] out);

        assign out = {`shamt{rt[31]}, rt >> shamt};

endmodule
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an arithmetic right shift:

```
assign out = rt >>> shamt;
```

This is documented in section **11.4.10 Shift operators** of the [IEEE 1800-2012 Specification](https://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to shift it in one cycle then you can do it like that: [example](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/3H2F)

This will synthesize but you should check if it will match your timing requirements. If you need to extend shamt port then you need to write another shift function. Anyway if you don't need to shift in one cycle then you should add registers between each call to shift function for better timing.

Comment: So all the 5 iterations of i should complete in 1 cycle?

Comment: If you want to shift in one cycle then yes, but if you can wait a couple of cycles for shift result then you can add registers between each loop iteration. What is more this code can be parametrized for any width of shamt but if you need to write a code only for shamt width = 5 then you can leave a for loop and just do checking like this: `if(shamt[0]) shift1(); if(shamt[1]) shift2(); ... `

Comment: Kamil- using edaplayground is great, but you should also post your code directly into your answer so users don't have to leave the site to see the answer.